# Sed (or awk) replace hosts found in list

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Sorry for the confusing title, I can't quite phrase what I'm trying to do in without examples.

I have a string of commands that I run that produces an output that looks like the following:

```
Host_A
Host_B
Net_X
Group_Y
```

so on and so forth

I want to then take that output and feed it into sed, so that it will replace any instance of a string found in the previous list with a new string, such as Host_Q.

```
sed 's/Host_A/Host_Q/g'
```

Works fine, however I'd like to avoid having to write a sed string for each host manually.

Thanks!

Edit: Better example

grep stream produces:

```
Host_A
Host_B
Host_C
Host_D
+lots more
```

I want to pipe that grep stream to sed, and have sed replace all instances of those hosts with a new (although identical) hostname.

Editx2: Also, the list is dynamic. So each type I run this against a new file, the contents will be different, which is why I can't (and don't want to) hardcode the original values.

EDIT:::

I figured it out on my own, sorry guys.

I'm taking the stream like so:

```
awk '{print "sed \x27s\/"$1"/HOST_Q/g\x27"}'
```

Sorry for being so damned confusing

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829445/multiple-regex-replacements-based-on-lists-in-multiple-files or at least the solution for this question can be found in that thread.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and I am not sure I understand it correctly, can you be more specific?

Comment: Did the edit make it better?

Comment: so you want to automatically replace Host_A -> Host_Q, Host_B -> Host_W or something? And do this replacement for every occurrence of these words in your program's output?

Comment: Host_A -> Host_Q | Host_B -> Host_Q, etc. All have to be converted to Host_Q. And yes, all instances

Comment: The edit didn't, but your above comment ;-) It was not clear to me whether there was only one target string, or if you wanted to group several replacements into one sed command as shown by kevro.

Comment: I edited again with the string I was actually looking for >.<

Comment: Can you explain your ultimate goal nevertheless? I have a feeling that you are overcomplicating things, even though it *worksforyou* now.

Comment: Sure. I run some search strings against file X. I then need to take the output from that search and modify a separate file, changing all hosts found in the original search to Host_Q

Comment: What you posted as the solution you figured out on your own is pretty goofy. You're using awk to generate sed to execute on your files - does that really sound like a good approach? Also this approach will fail in cryptic ways if any of your strings contain RE metacharacters.

Comment: Nope, not at all, but it works >.<

Comment: Hmm, it may appear to be working right now for some sample input you have but it definitely doesn't do what you asked for. To clarify, it will work if your file of text to be replaced only contains alpha-numeric or underscore characters, but if it contains anything else beware of the ensuing nasal demons!

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to put multiple replace strings in the same command like this?

```
mycommands | sed '
s/Host_A/Host1/g 
s/Host_B/Host2/g 
s/Net_X/Net1/g 
s/Group_Y/Group2/g'
```

Or to create a command file like this:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/Host_A/Host1/g 
s/Host_B/Host2/g 
s/Net_X/Net1/g 
s/Group_Y/Group2/g'
```

Save this script as a file like "chgnames" and make it executable, you could use it with the simple command:

mycommands | ./chgnames

Comment: I see you just modified your question :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry :) - should be 's/*/Host_Q/g' for the lot of them

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's#^\(Host_A\|Host_B\)$#Host_Q#'
```

That?

Comment: That's too specific. I want everything from the output of the grep to be converted. The whole point is to *not* have to type of the original content of the list.

Comment: Now we are back to square one. If you replace "everything" in your output to Host_Q, then why are you grepping in the first place? My guess is that your question is wrong and your output is not just one column showing the hostname, because then this would be absolutely useless and just print Host_Q x times output lines of grep. Please elaborate :-)

Comment: Another wild guess: Is your goal to take this list and replace these hostnames to Host_Q in _another_ file?